# Wordpress Configuration File

Tags: wordpress, installation, configuration-files

I have insatlled wordpress 3.3.1 recently. I have not confirgured wp-config.php file before installation, after installation, i have copied the wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php & edit the details accordingly, but this wp-config file is not reflecting actually.

What may be the reason, how to make this enable so that wp-config file will be included while loading wordpress files,

Moreover from where the db & other settings are loaded in Wordpress.

Thanks !

Comment: Could you be more specific when you say it is not reflecting. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I think it had be loaded from wp-config.php in root directory of wordpress, are you copying it to right directory?

Comment: When i add any constants to the config file, that constants cant be accessed ?  if i change the db name also, still the blog is working fine. So the details of the DB are stored somewhere and accessed. I want to know where it is stored actually. in database ??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that wp-config.php is in the right location (webroot), and that the file has the appropriate permissions. If everything checks out ok, check the apache logs.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you follow the [following steps](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/useful-wordpress-configuration-tricks-that-you-may-not-know/)

I can only assume you are on a windows machine, since I've had the same problem, but not in Linux.